# Variables must either be defined within the `cy.origin()` command or passed in using the args option

Tags: cypress

I am trying to implement page object model using cypress and my project structure is so:
A .js file with various methods
A .json file in fixtures
A .cy.js with the tests

I have the following code in the .js

```
  enterUsername(username) {
    cy.origin("https://***********",() => {
      cy.get('input[id="username"]').type(username); 
   });
   return this;
   }
```

The **test code** looks like this

```
 login.enterUsername(this.loginData.user1);
```

**Fixtures**

```
{
  "user1": "login-st-su-re-ad-gls"
}
```

and I also have this hook in support.e2e cypress

```
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture('loginData').then((loginData) => {
      expect(loginData, 'the same data').to.deep.equal(loginData)
  }); 
});
```

The idea is to make the code reusable and call the same methods for different users. When I run my tests I get this error. Looking for ideas on how to fix this.

ReferenceError: username is not defined

*Variables must either be defined within the `cy.origin()` command or passed in using the args option.

Using `require()` or `import()` within the `cy.origin()` callback is not supported. Use `Cypress.require()` to include dependencies instead, but note that it currently requires enabling the `experimentalOriginDependencies` flag.*

I also tried this solution but it didn't yield any positive results

```
enterUsername(username) {
  cy.origin("https://********", { args: { username } }, () => {
    cy.get('input[id="username"]').type(username);
  });
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the [examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Examples), you are missing the receiving parameter

```js
enterUsername(username) {
  cy.origin("https://********", 
    { args: { username } }, 
    ({ username }) => {                          <-- here is the parameter
      cy.get('input[id="username"]').type(username);
    }
  );
  return this;
}
```